# Is there any Stack Exchange site where I can ask questions related to planning of project?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

We are planning developing an E-commerce marketplace site in PHP, and **before doing coding** we want to list the requirements like:

- Features of **login, products, orders, payments**
- How these sections are connected to each other

Also what and all **fields & tables do we need to create in the database** for these?

On which Stack Exchange site, if any, can I ask these questions?

Is there any Stack Exchange site to help regarding planning of a project?

Comment: What question do you exactly want to ask? You want to verify the completeness and correctness of your requirements? Your design? Your choice of programming stack? All of these are too broad / only useful for you which are in general not a good fit for any Stack Exchange site. If you want to ask about doubts you have about planning you need to be more precise what you exactly need.

Comment: @rene Thanks for suggestion, you are absolutely right, i complete agree on `only useful for you which are in general not a good fit for any Stack Exchange site.`

Comment: @cssbeginner as with any site/questionyou need to ask something focussed and not generic or it will get closed as too broad. You'll need to do plenty of research on programmers first. Look carefully at previously asked questions under tags you think might be appropriate.

Comment: @RobertLongson sure, i will do that first..... Thanks.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software architecture and design is on-topic on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

As with any site, you should check their [help centre](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and look at what sort of questions have been upvoted/downvoted and therefore what details you'll need to provide to get the best result there.

Comment: But I highly doubt that what the OP lists here is going to end-up in a great question. Sending them to programmers.se is going to end in a disaster as they are even more concerned about their quality of posts then on SO. This answer is not helping.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, i will look at the `help center` of programmers.se & try to ask valid questions otherwise i think they will kick me out from asking questions :-)

Comment: @cssbeginner the more research you do first, the better question you'll likely ask. You may well find that some of the existing questions and their answers help not just to formulate your problem properly but also answer it.